# Deauthorise Facebook app using the API

Tags: php, facebook, api

Is it possible to deauthorise my own app using the API [assuming I have sufficient permissions]?

I'm writing some unit tests and want to be able to register/unregister the app programatically (I'm aware the register step requires user input)

I'm working in PHP so calls are being made to the various URLs eg to logout:

```
header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=" . urlencode($ReturnUrl) . "&access_token=" . $Params['access_token']);
```

For calls that return data, I'm using `file_get_contents()`.

I'm already handling all the OAuth tokens.

I need a solution I can use server-side not JavaScript / browser automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `HTTP DELETE` request to `/PROFILE_ID/permissions` with your user's access token (I think the App Access Token will work here too)

- e.g. in PHP using the SDK it may look like :

> $user_id = 'user id here';
>
> $facebook->api($user.'/permissions','DELETE');